# How to search Stack Overflow for string containing < and > characters?

Tags: support, search, special-characters

Is it possible to search Stack Overflow for a string containing < and > characters?

I'm trying to find questions relating to **Where<T>** but get told there are no results for **WhereT**. This makes it difficult to find information on questions relating to C# generics.

Comment: SO Search sucks. Everyone knows that!

Comment: use double quotes: ["Where<T>"] unfortunately this is the only question it finds.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the ` character or double quotes to your search terms, e.g.,

```Where``` `` or " ```Where`"

Answer (score 8):

Stick to using google searches with the site:stackoverflow.com modifier

Comment: Or just go here: http://www.google.com/coop/cse?cx=018205968162215846785:7n6ajnwyz-i

Comment: Never seen that before. Is there a way I can add that to my list of search engine's in the firefox search bar? Otherwise it is likely faster for me to just type it in as I normally do.

Comment: I'm not sure: you used to be able to add search providers by URL but I don't see how to do that anymore.

Comment: Personally, I just keep the link handy on my user profile page.

Comment: It's a good idea, I am just so hard-wired to the search box now that anything else seems like going out of my way :)